# Twitter4j how can i get any twitter handle tweets from it's 1'st tweets

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

i am using this code i get an error TwitterException 429
trying to fecth the tweets.
i want to fecth whole tweets of twitter account from starting.
how to solve twitter rate limit issue.

```
    int limitRateCounter=0;
int countOfTweets=0; int numberOfTweets = 3500; long lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE; ArrayList<Status> status = new ArrayList<Status>();while (status.size () < numberOfTweets) { try {.out.print("\nlimit counter = "+limitRateCounter);.out.print("\t tweetsCounter = "+countOfTweets);
List<Status>  listOfStatus=
twitter.getUserTimeline(tweeterHandle,pg);
/* making twitter request */
countOfTweets=countOfTweets+listOfStatus.size();
status.addAll(listOfStatus);
limitRateCounter++; 
// println("Gathered " + tweets.size() + " tweets");
for (Status t: status) 
if(t.getId() < lastID) lastID = t.getId();
}
catch (TwitterException te) {
System.out.println("Couldn't connect: " + te);
//twitter=getTwitterDetails2();
break;
}; 
pg.setMaxId(lastID-1); /* add pagging max id */
}
```

after 120 request .getUserTimeline(tweeterHandle,pg); methode not fetching 
new tweets after some time get exception.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter4j uses Twitter API to access Twitter data. This API has limits in the number of invocations as is specified here:

- [API Rate Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting)
- [Rate Limits Charts](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits)

You seem to be facing this problem right now. Basically your code needs to wait before making another call until you are again inside the API rate limits. Take into account that the rate limit is per "access token" as the documentation specifies, so you could increase the number of calls your code can make if you provide it with more access tokens, but in the end you will have a (bigger) limit.

Comment: thanks BitExodus you know any another java API which gives me a tweitter history.

Comment: i am using 2 tokens for increasing calls but second one not fetch any new tweets .

Comment: The problem you are facing is not in the java library, is in the API Twitter provides which has rate limits (I mean Twitter servers). The java library is only a tool to let you call the Twitter API and any other library will face the same problem. You can try waiting 15 minutes before making another call when the limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

create several accounts on twitter (10) then put access tokens in array